# How can I find a member using their tag?

Tags: discord.js

As the title says, I'm trying to find a member by their tag but the code I used doesn't work.

```js
msg.guild.members.cache.find((m) => m.tag == 'Test User#1234');
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `tag` belongs to `User`, not `GuildMember`. So you'll have to use `GuildMember.User.tag`.

---

```js
const Member = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == "Test User#1234");

if (!Member) return message.channel.send(`Couldn't find the user.`);

message.channel.send(`Found ${Member.user.tag}`);
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas?


`var str = "Test User#1234";
var lgnth = str.indexOf('#') + 5;
var findMember = msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == str.slice(0, lgnth));

if (typeof findMember !== "undefined") {
    msg.channel.send(\`${findMember}\`);
} else {
    msg.channel.send(\`Member does not exist.\`);
}`

Comment: After more testing, I learned that if it includes spaces, it doesn't work.

Comment: The code I provided is working even if the user has a space in the username.